# Why my ARIMA prediction is considerably smaller that the real values?

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

I'm a kind of new in working with time series. After guarantee that the serie is stationary, I used the function SARIMAX from statsmodels to tried predict the time series. It results in a smaller scale in comparison with the real values, and this difference of scale becomes more evident when I re-transform these series(undoing the .log().diff()).
I make the data stationary in this way:

```
log_btc = np.log(sum['closeBTC'])
diff_log_btc = log_btc - log_btc.shift()
```

After applying a ARIMA model, I retransform the data:

```
predictions_ARIMA_diff = pd.Series(model_fit.fittedvalues, copy=True)
predictions_ARIMA_diff_cumsum = predictions_ARIMA_diff.cumsum()
predictions_ARIMA_log = pd.Series(log_btc.iloc[0], index=log_btc.index)
predictions_ARIMA_log =predictions_ARIMA_log.add(predictions_ARIMA_diff_cumsum,fill_value=0)
predictions_ARIMA = np.exp(predictions_ARIMA_log)
```

Here are the plots
Real values:
[real values plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgiqv.png)

Predicted with ARIMA:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2ryY.png)

Does anyone can answer why the predictions are in such a different scale and how can i fix this?

[image: a image about the problem]

Comment: It is just less variable - this is expected since it removes the noise, which is why the blue line has a wider range than the red. Formally it must always be the case that the variance of the conditional expectation (the forecast) is smaller than the variance of the underlying random variables.

Comment: that doesn't mean my model isn't good, does it? I was trying to compare this model with another one, with an exogenous series. The problem is when I re-transform the model, it seems that on account of the variance be smaller, it makes that my prediction be in a huge difference of scale in comparison to the real value. Do you have any idea if i'm making a mistake(maybe, in the re-transformation)?

Comment: You should edit your post with more code, ideally runnable.  There isn't enough here to provide meaningful help.

Comment: Ok. I  edited. if you could help, i would appreciate it.